# Standard error of prediction MARS splines earth package

Tags: r, machine-learning, caret, mars

I'm using the earth package (using caret train function) MARS spline implementation in order to perform non - linear regression modeling. I would like to obtain a measure of prediction uncertainty (not only the expected value). Is there any way to obtain it? Thanks in advance for any help.

Comment: Probably bootstrap is the only way.

Answer (score 2):

Prediction intervals are supported by earth version 4.0.0 (Dec 2014) and higher. See the vignette [Variance models in earth](http://www.milbo.org/doc/earth-varmod.pdf) that comes with the earth package. You can generate plots such as the following:

[image: plot]